# cordova-plugin-apple-watch plugin issue

Tags: cordova-plugins, apple-watch, cordova-ios

Hi I am calling the init method of cordova-plugin-apple-watch plugin in our cordova application , but it is not returning to neither successhandler or errorhandler.

```
 isWatchPairingExists: function() {
       var deferred = new Deferred();
       console.log("gdfgd");
       applewatch.init(successHandler, errorHandler, "group.com.company.app");
       function successHandler() {
         console.log("rrrr");
                alert("binding  exist");
              return  deferred.resolve(true);
       }
        function errorHandler() {
        console.log("ewrwrwr");
            alert("binding does not exist");
             return deferred.resolve(false);
       }

     return deferred.promise;
    }

  };
```

I am really grateful , if anyone can help on this.

Comment: Can you give detailed information about your problem?